# using mysqlbinlog utility in windows

Tags: mysql

MySql commandline  in windows in my machine doesn't recognize
 mysqlbinlog utility.I get below error.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'mysqlbinlog' at line 1

Do I need to have a file related with mysqlbinlog in mysql/bin?

If not then how should I run the mysqlbinlog utility?I can see binary logs by running show binary logs on mysql command prompt .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqlbinlog utility is mandatory for running mysqlbinlog.Somehow my windows mysql installation is missing the same.